# MySQL UPDATE not updating properly

Tags: mysql

I've got an UPDATE query as followed:

```
UPDATE orders 
SET 
    order_status = 1,
    amount_remaining = 0.00000000
WHERE
    market_pair_id = 2 AND user_id = 1
        AND sale_rate = 0.00000001
        AND sale_amount = 100.00000000
        AND order_type = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Here's a snapshot of my data from phpmyadmin:

http://cl.ly/image/3m3M2f2R3R3Z/Screen%20Shot%202014-01-20%20at%2012.55.03.png

There's clearly 3 matching rows for my query however none of them are updated with the message 0 rows affected. Can someone shed light on what's going on?

Some added info: I can't update via the primary key because I dont have it, and my goal is simply to update 1 of many matching rows of my data.

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: If you wrap the values in quotes, does it still not work?

Comment: Try to `select` using the same criteria, if it doesn't work, then it's not finding the data for some reason, quotes might help. If it does, and still update doesn't work, try to add a `commit` and see what happens.

Comment: This is because you use double values for comparison in where clause. Use double values in comparison is not reliable.

Comment: Would it be possible to have a sample of your data in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: Here's an SQL fiddle showing it working, it doesnt work in my phpmyadmin or actual site script. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aeb71/3

Answer (score 0):

Delete `LIMIT 1` from end of your query and try

```
UPDATE orders 
    SET 
        order_status = 1,
        amount_remaining = 0.00000000
    WHERE
        market_pair_id = 2 AND user_id = 1
            AND sale_rate = 0.00000001
            AND sale_amount = 100.00000000
            AND order_type = 1
```

Comment: This works but it updates 2 out of the 3 rows, rather than the desired 1 out of 3.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand you what do you mean by 2 out of 3 rows. This query shoul update the rows that matches where clause

Answer (score 0):

.try this

```
 UPDATE orders 
 SET 
    order_status = 1,
    amount_remaining = 0.00000000
 WHERE order_id IN (
     SELECT order_id FROM (
         SELECT order_id FROM orders 
          WHERE market_pair_id = 2 
          AND user_id = 1
          AND sale_rate = 0.00000001
          AND sale_amount = 100.00000000
          AND order_type = 1  
         LIMIT 1
     ) tmp
 );
```

Comment: 0 rows affected, as they are stored as decimals(32,8)

Comment: For a second I thought it worked, but it doesn't. I found out that if all the data is the same in the table it works, but if theres different data (different amounts and rates) it fails to work, same as my original query as i tested that too again.

Comment: of course it fails because you are making those conditions they must be right, if you want those conditions one of them be right then make OR instead of AND.